# Cocos2d/iOS: can't understand how to interpet a pointer address

Tags: ios, pointers, memory, cocos2d-iphone

I have a `NSMutableArray` containing 200 bullets (sublcass of `CCSprite`) created as following:

```
capacity=200;
bullets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:capacity];

// Create a number of bullets up front and re-use them whenever necessary.
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
{
    Bullet* bullet = [Bullet bulletWithScreenRect:screenRect];
    bullet.visible = NO;
    bullet.bulletId=i;
    [bullets addObject:bullet];
    [self addChild:bullet]; 
}
```

I created a for loop to iterate them and added a breakpoint to see if the address was the same.

```
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
{
    Bullet* bullet = [bullets objectAtIndex:i];
    CCLOG(@"%i %i", i, bullet.bulletId);
}
```

**The result is that the pointer "bullet" always refers to the same address in memory for all 200 bullets (0x1336c8a0)**. I added a property in bullet (int:bulletId) to try identify if they are different objects or not but it seems so. **I don't understand why the pointer has always to the same address (does it refer to the same address? or is it just the pointer memory address?).**

Here is where I get the 0x1336c8a0 address from the `Bullet*` pointer:

[image: Here is where I get the 0x1336c8a0 address from the <code>Bullet*</code> pointer]

Answer (score 0):

I would look in the bulletWithScreenRect method of the Bullet class.  I assume this is a factory method, but maybe it just returns the same static object.   You could alloc and init the Bullet object yourself, and then I assume there is a way to set the screen rectangle separately.

In other words, change:

```
  Bullet* bullet = [Bullet bulletWithScreenRect:screenRect];
```

To something like this:

```
  Bullet* bullet = [[Bullet alloc] init];
  bullet.screenRect = screenRect;  // Not sure if this setter is present.
```

At the very least, just for a sanity check you can change the constructor of the Bullet class, to ensure you are creating separate instances.  Like I said, check the contents of the bulletWithScreenRect method to see what it is really doing.  That seems like the culprit to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well that means that you only have one instance of `Bullet` in your array. In that case, your problem is definitely in your `bulletWithScreenRect` method, which returns a cached instance instead of a new one.

The address you're seeing the debugger is the address to which the pointer is pointing not the address of the pointer, which would be more or less useless. Since the address to which the pointer is pointing is always the same, it's clear that we're talking about the same object.

To test what I've just said, you could print the address and compare it to the value you get in the debugger:

```
NSLog(@"Pointer own address: %p", &bullet);
NSLog(@"Address to where the pointer is pointing: %p", bullet); //this is what you should get in the debugger
```